# Split a variable line by line

Tags: command-line, search, grep

I initialize variable like this:

```
dmesgDevs=$(dmesg | grep idVendor)
```

and want to print it line by line and then check if theres is word in particular line.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping more lines in a variable can be really painful. In fact when you use only `dmesg | grep idVendor` the output will be arranged in more lines, but when you do `dmesgDevs=$(dmesg | grep idVendor)`, all the lines will be merged in a single string.

Now, to print `dmesgDevs` line by line, you can set the [internal field separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator) (IFS) variable, and then let it parse into an array. Something like this it will parse each time one line of input separated by `[`:

```
while IFS='[' read ADDR; do for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do echo $i; done; done <<< "$dmesgDevs"
```

Finally, to check if theres is word in particular line, just pipe the output of previous command to `grep`:

```
while IFS='[' read ADDR; do for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do echo $i; done; done <<< "$dmesgDevs" | grep 'word'
```

---

In this case I was able to find a solution because each line start with the same pattern (`[`), but this doesn't happen all the time. So, as alternative instead to keep the output of `dmesg | grep idVendor` command in a variable, keep it in a file; for example in `/tmp/dmesgDevs`. You can do this using:

```
dmesg | grep idVendor > /tmp/dmesgDevs
```

Then, everything is very simple:

```
cat /tmp/dmesgDevs
grep 'word' /tmp/dmesgDevs
```